# Auto-Populating to create 1 list in 1 column based on data from two different columns (Google sheets)

Tags: list, google-sheets, array-formulas

Having some trouble with a very simple problem. I want to create 1 list in a column based on data from two different columns, I only want each item to appear once in the list column.

So to create the list based on data from one column, I used this formula but I don't know how to do it from 2 (and the number of occurrences/count isn't needed).

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(J2:J&{"",""},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Number of occurrences'",-1))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1loPw3eUALLKx3NzXrxhDszqD2_B7G3cyH1EhnYg4tFg/edit?ts=5cf63f94#gid=0

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
=sort(UNIQUE({A1:A10;B1:B12}))
```

If your locale uses `,` as separator, the lists are in A1:A10 and B1:B12 and you want the result sorted.